# Programmatically create a photo album in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing app for Windows Phone 8 which will allow users to download icons. It will be right if the app could be able to programmatically create custom photo album in pictures hub and save icons there and not save images in standard folder called `Saved Images`.

Is there a way to create a photo album in Windows Phone 8 and save images to that folder ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696400/how-to-create-a-photo-album-folder-in-windows-phone-8-programmatically/22119768#22119768 , this is for WP8.1, see if that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how I can put this.. let me do it the easiest way..

No you can not create custom folder on the phone's picture lib.

However, you can use skydrive and create a folder there and use that to do whatever you need to do.

it is accessible from the photo album on the device.

Hermit

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

The only options available when saving to the media library are to save to the [Camera Roll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicturetocameraroll%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) or the [Saved Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) folders.