# How to create a photo album folder in Windows Phone 8 Programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have seen many questions about this topic. All answers are saying it is not possible and all questions are answered like that only.

Here is one [Programmatically create a photo album in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113666/programmatically-create-a-photo-album-in-windows-phone-8)

But after installing the latest WhatsApp update it is creating a folder in my phone photo album. After searching the internet I got this URL: http://thegeekybeng.com/2013/12/18/whatsapp-for-windows-phone-get-a-much-needed-update/

> .. What's more! Now it's easier to search for the videos and photos you
>   Saved from whatsapp as a new folder simply named “Whatsapp” will be
>   Created in the photo album for you to store all the videos and photos
>   Saved from Whatsapp!...

How is this possible?

Comment: Because of this Problem My two WP apps Stopped ...:(...Any One say How it's Possibly for Whats App

Comment: check Neil Turner's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757538/save-pictures-to-custom-folder-in-media-library/20761428#comment31135201_20761428

Comment: Possible helpful solutions: 1. [PhotoHub - Windows Phone 8 XAML LongListSelector Grid Layout sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093) 2. [Creating beautiful views for local files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/23/creating-beautiful-views-for-local-files.aspx) 3. [MediaLibrary.SavePicture Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx)

Comment: @JSuar I am ok with saving file in album. But I am looking for same image in my own folder, Same like WhatsApp.

Comment: Hai @NagaHarishMovva are You saving Images In Separate folder Like WhatsApp ..if You done that Can You Post the Code as Answer Hear

Comment: @SriramSatti I am doing R&D my side. Still it is unknown. Once I got solution I will try to update here. May be it is in latest SDK it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How is this possible." This is only possible if you have access to API's/other means that are not publicly available, look at [this](http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/12/18/whatsapp-arrives-for-windows-phone-8/) news report from Nokia for example, it states

> The developers were working with Nokia to produce a version that is
>   properly optimised for the latest Windows Phone platform experience.

This means that the WhatsApp developers had access to some of the internal goodies that we "unworthy" developers do not.

This is the only explanation I can think of. So, is it possible? Yes, but only for the elite.

EDIT:

In WP8.1 you could do this:

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> storageFolderList = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();
if (storageFolderList.Where(x => x.Name == "FolderName").Count() == 0)
{
    StorageFolder folderCreationResult = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("FolderName", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("FolderName has been created", "Folder Created");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
else
{
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("FolderName already exists.", "Folder Exists");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been now provided to all developers finally through Windows 8.1 update and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

```
KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("My Album Name", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```