# Save pictures to custom folder in media library

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, media, sd-card

WhatsApp now saves pictures to a custom folder named "WhatsApp" in the media library.
Is WhatsApp using a undocumented API or is this possible for every developer?
Right now I am only aware of the possibility to save pictures to the "Camera Roll" or to the "Saved Pictures".

Comment: You can check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696400/how-to-create-a-photo-album-folder-in-windows-phone-8-programmatically/22119768#22119768 , this is for WP8.1, see if it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears WhatsApp has special permission to do that as no current APIs for Windows Phone 8 (with GDR3) allow you to specify a folder name.

The hope is that Windows Phone 8.1 will introduce new APIs for both saving pictures and video.

Comment: I agree,There are other things that are not possible with current Sdk( or we don't know a way yet). I think Microsoft is giving a special APIs for special developers. For Example Check MoliPlayer pro which has access to read and write videos in camera roll and  SdCard!

Comment: @AhmedRashad agreed, there is a growing list of apps with 'special permissions'. I hope these extra features are a preview of what's to come in WP 8.1

Comment: Does anyone know how to apply for that special api?

Comment: @esskar you would need a contact in Nokia or Microsoft - Windows Phone 8.1 should fix a lot of these restrictions for all developers.